# How to return the index of a string found in another string?

Tags: python, string, indexing

I have a list of words that I stored in 'dict_words'.
What I'm looking for is looking for the existence of the words in a file.

So for each line I do like below in order to get whether any word of 'dict_words' appears in the line:

```
with open(filename, "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    if any(re.findall(r'|'.join(dict_words), line, re.IGNORECASE)):
      #get the index of the word in 'dict_words'
```

After this condition reached (ie: True), I want to get the index of the word found in the 'dict_words' but I don't have any idea of what I have to do.
I want something that is performant (quick) because the file is composed of a series of long texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use:

```
indexes = [] # where the indexes are stored
with open(filename, "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    findall = re.findall(r'|'.join(dict_words), line, re.IGNORECASE)
    if any(findall):
      indexes.append(dict_words.index(findall[0]))
```

Comment: @Yasmine Happy to help, don't forget to accept it if it works :-)

Comment: @Yasmine check it again, it doesn't seem like you did it

Comment: Why `findall[0]`? If you have found many words? Isn't `any()` redundant?

Comment: @MykolaZotko `re.findall` provides a list, here it would be one element in the list, so still, get the first one

Comment: Your solution worked to get the index of the word but now I get errors from other things

Comment: @Yasmine Is it better now?

Comment: Not yet. I'm still trying to fix it.

Comment: I did not downvote, but as a slight improvement you could compile the regex outside of the loop: `rx=re.compile(r'|'.join(dict_words) for line in file: findall=rx.findall(line, re.IGNORE_CASE)`

Comment: Thank you for your help @U9-Forward . Now the errors are fixed!

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the first match I would use `search()` instead of `findall()` (it's faster):

```
import re

s = 'This is a test string'
l = ['test' 'is', 'string']

first_match = re.search(r'|'.join(l), s)
if first_match:
    ind = l.index(first_match.group())
    print(ind)
# 1
```

If you use `findall()` you don't need `any()` in the `if` statement: `if re.findall()`. The function `findall()` returns a list, which can be either empty or filled with matches.